# Gazebo model_states

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

My question is very simple: What I'm doing wrong????

I did a easy subscriptor:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/ModelState.h"

void chatterCallback(const gazebo_msgs::ModelState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    int i = 0;

    ROS_INFO("I heard: %d", i);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("gazebo/model_states",1000, chatterCallback);
    ROS_INFO("IN ");
    ros::Duration(1,0).sleep();
    ROS_INFO("OUT ");
 
    ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

And the resoult is:

> ./bin/listener

```
[ INFO] [1352123368.021140417]: IN 
[ INFO] [1352123369.264976085, 18.667000000]: OUT 
(.. nothing ..)
```

While I do: (I obtain a lot of topic)

rostopic echo /gazebo/model_states

Regars.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47486/gazebo-model_states/) by [Sanxano](https://answers.ros.org/users/1103/sanxano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are using the wrong message type when subscribing. The type is ModelStates, not ModelState. Change your include line and the signature of the function chatterCallback and it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3